# The number of solutions solved after FullSimplify processing is different from the number of solutions directly solved

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Firstly, define the function as follows:

```
h[l_, p_, \[Gamma]_] := 
  2^(Abs[l] + 2) p! (Abs[l] + 
      p)! \[Gamma]^2 (Sum[((-2)^m Gamma[
          m + Abs[l]/2 + 
           1])/((p - m)! (Abs[l] + m)! m! (1 + \[Gamma]^2)^(m + 
            Abs[l]/2 + 1)), {m, 0, p}])^2;
```

**Way1**: Solve its extreme value (when $p=1$)

```
h1 = h[l, 1, \[Gamma]] // FullSimplify
```

> (2 Sqrt[[Pi]] [Gamma]^2 (1 + [Gamma]^2)^(-4 -
> Abs[l]) (-1 + [Gamma]^2 + [Gamma]^2 Abs[l])^2 Gamma[
> 1 + Abs[l]/2])/Gamma[1/2 (3 + Abs[l])]

```
Solve[D[h1, \[Gamma]] == 0, \[Gamma]] // FullSimplify
```

> {{[Gamma] -> 0}, {[Gamma] -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]])}, {[Gamma] -> 1/
> Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]]}}

**Way2**: Solve its extreme value (when $p=1$)

```
D[h1, \[Gamma]] // FullSimplify;
Solve[% == 0, \[Gamma]] // FullSimplify
```

> {{[Gamma] -> 0}, {[Gamma] -> ComplexInfinity}, {[Gamma] ->
> ComplexInfinity}, {[Gamma] -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]])}, {[Gamma] ->
> 1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]]}, {[Gamma] -> -(1/Sqrt[
> 3 + 2 Abs[l] + Sqrt[
> 8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]]])}, {[Gamma] -> 1/Sqrt[
> 3 + 2 Abs[l] + Sqrt[
> 8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]]]}, {[Gamma] -> -Sqrt[(1/(
> 3 + 2 Abs[l] - Sqrt[
> 8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]]))]}, {[Gamma] -> Sqrt[1/(
> 3 + 2 Abs[l] - Sqrt[8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]])]}}

Why does the number of solutions obtained with the same approach differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

h[l_, p_, γ_] := 2^(Abs[l] + 2) p! (Abs[l] + 
      p)! γ^2 (Sum[((-2)^m Gamma[m + Abs[l]/2 + 
           1])/((p - m)! (Abs[l] + m)! m! (1 + γ^2)^(m + Abs[l]/2 + 
            1)), {m, 0, p}])^2;

h1 = h[l, 1, γ] // FullSimplify

(* (2 Sqrt[π] γ^2 (1 + γ^2)^(-4 - 
  Abs[l]) (-1 + γ^2 + γ^2 Abs[l])^2 Gamma[1 + Abs[l]/2])/Gamma[
 1/2 (3 + Abs[l])] *)

sol1S = Solve[D[h1, γ] == 0, γ] // FullSimplify

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{γ -> 0}, {γ -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]])}, {γ -> 1/Sqrt[
   1 + Abs[l]]}} *)
```

The warning message tells you that the solution may be incomplete and to use [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
sol1R = {Reduce[D[h1, γ] == 0, γ] // FullSimplify // 
    ToRules} /. (γ + a_ -> b_) :> (γ -> b - a)

(* {{γ -> 0}, {γ -> 1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]]}, {γ -> 
   Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 1] + 
    I Root[(6 + 4 Abs[l] - 
           6 Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &,
              1]^2 - 12 Abs[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             1]^2 - 6 l Conjugate[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             1]^2) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + l Conjugate[l]) #1^4 &, 
      2]}, {γ -> 
   Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 2] + 
    I Root[(6 + 4 Abs[l] - 
           6 Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &,
              2]^2 - 12 Abs[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             2]^2 - 6 l Conjugate[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             2]^2) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + l Conjugate[l]) #1^4 &, 
      1]}, {γ -> 
   Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 3] + 
    I Root[(6 + 4 Abs[l] - 
           6 Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &,
              3]^2 - 12 Abs[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             3]^2 - 6 l Conjugate[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             3]^2) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + l Conjugate[l]) #1^4 &, 
      1]}, {γ -> 
   Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 4] + 
    I Root[(6 + 4 Abs[l] - 
           6 Root[1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &,
              4]^2 - 12 Abs[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             4]^2 - 6 l Conjugate[l] Root[
             1 + (-6 - 4 Abs[l]) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + Abs[l]^2) #1^4 &, 
             4]^2) #1^2 + (1 + 2 Abs[l] + l Conjugate[l]) #1^4 &, 
      2]}, {γ -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]])}} *)
```

If you restrict the domain to [`Reals`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reals.html) you get simpler results

```
sol1Sr = Solve[D[h1, γ] == 0, γ, Reals] // FullSimplify

(* {{γ -> 0}, {γ -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]])}, {γ -> 1/Sqrt[
   1 + Abs[l]]}, {γ -> -(Sqrt[
    3 + 2 Abs[l] - Sqrt[(2 + Abs[l]) (4 + 3 Abs[l])]]/(
    1 + Abs[l]))}, {γ -> Sqrt[
   3 + 2 Abs[l] - Sqrt[(2 + Abs[l]) (4 + 3 Abs[l])]]/(
   1 + Abs[l])}, {γ -> -(Sqrt[
    3 + 2 Abs[l] + Sqrt[(2 + Abs[l]) (4 + 3 Abs[l])]]/(
    1 + Abs[l]))}, {γ -> Sqrt[
   3 + 2 Abs[l] + Sqrt[(2 + Abs[l]) (4 + 3 Abs[l])]]/(1 + Abs[l])}} *)

Length /@ {sol1S, sol1R}

(* {3, 7} *)
```

`sol1S` is a subset of `sol1R`

```
SubsetQ[sol1R, sol1S]

(* True *)
```

Your second case is different in that you simplify both prior to and after solving. Eliminating the [`ComplexInfinity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ComplexInfinity.html) results,

```
der = D[h1, γ] // FullSimplify;

sol2S = Select[Solve[der == 0, γ] // FullSimplify,
  FreeQ[#, ComplexInfinity] &]

(* Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.

{{γ -> 0}, {γ -> -(1/Sqrt[1 + Abs[l]])}, {γ -> 1/Sqrt[
   1 + Abs[l]]}, {γ -> -(1/Sqrt[
    3 + 2 Abs[l] + Sqrt[8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]]])}, {γ -> 1/
   Sqrt[3 + 2 Abs[l] + Sqrt[
    8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]]]}, {γ -> -Sqrt[(1/(
    3 + 2 Abs[l] - Sqrt[8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]]))]}, {γ -> 
   Sqrt[1/(3 + 2 Abs[l] - Sqrt[8 + 10 Abs[l] + 3 l Conjugate[l]])]}} *)
```

However, without restricting the domain to `Reals`, `Reduce` cannot handle this

```
Reduce[der == 0, γ]

(* Reduce::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Reduce.

Reduce[-((4 Sqrt[π] γ (1 + γ^2)^(-5 - 
        Abs[l]) (-1 + γ^2 + γ^2 Abs[l]) (1 - 
         6 γ^2 + γ^4 + 2 γ^2 (-2 + γ^2) Abs[l] + 
         l γ^4 Conjugate[l]) Gamma[1 + Abs[l]/2])/
     Gamma[1/2 (3 + Abs[l])]) == 0, γ] *)
```

If you assume that `l` is real then `sol1Sr` is equal to `sol2S`

```
Assuming[l ∈ Reals, ((γ /. sol1Sr) - (γ /. sol2S)) // 
  FullSimplify]

(* {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

Numerically checking,

```
And @@ Table[lv = RandomReal[{-10, 10}];
  Sort[γ /. sol1R /. l -> lv] == Sort[γ /. sol2S /. l -> lv],
  50]

(* True *)
```

As Daniel pointed out, the solutions can split into pairs of solutions

```
sol2Sr = Solve[der == 0, γ, Reals] // FullSimplify
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[`FullSimplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullSimplify.html) performs transformations which are not necessarily equivalent. This is also mentioned under section *Possible Issues* in the documentation.

Given the example there:

```
expr = Gamma[1 - x] Gamma[x] Sin[Pi x];
exprSimple = FullSimplify[expr]
(* π *)

Solve[expr == 0]
(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[
      2*C[1], Element[C[1], Integers]]}, 
    {x -> ConditionalExpression[
      (Pi + 2*π*C[1])/π, Element[C[1], Integers]]}} *)

Solve[exprSimple == 0]
(* {} *)
```

Comment: In this case FullSimplify is unlikely to be implicated. Also I expect some of the extra values in the second case will turn out to be equal to others (nested square roots).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau, I don't think I fully understand your comment. Are you saying that it is `Solve` to be blamed for the different output and not `FullSimplify`?

Comment: I don’t think either is particularly wrong. Doing a parametrized summation and plugging in a parameter afterward is almost as fragile as doing same for a definite integral. And in this case results are different but not (at a glance) in obvious conflict.